# Problema com o cálculo da média em linguagem C

Tags: c, algoritmo, matemática

Estou fazendo este exercício:

> 4 - Escreva um algoritmo que leia um conjunto de 50 fichas, cada uma
> contendo a altura e o sexo de uma pessoa (1 = masculino e 2 =
> feminino), e calcule e imprima:
>
> - A maior e a menor altura da turma;
> - A média de altura da mulheres;
> - A média de altura da turma.

Tudo está rodando corretamente, menos a média das mulheres.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "PORTUGUESE");
    
    int i, somamulher, somaturma, genero[4];
    float maioralt=0, menoralt=999, mediaaltmulher, medaltturma, altura[4];

    
    printf("\n\n #######################################");
    printf("\n\n           ANÁLISE DE FICHAS");
    printf("\n\n #######################################");
    
    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\n ------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n\n (%i) - Qual seu gênero (1 - Masculino / 2 - Feminino): ", i+1);
        scanf("%i", &genero[i]);
        
        printf("\n (%i) - Insira sua altura: ", i+1);
        scanf("%f", &altura[i]);
        
        somaturma = somaturma + altura[i];
        system("cls");
    }
    
    //MEDIA MULHER
    if(genero[i] = 2)
    {
        somamulher = somamulher + 1;
    }
    
    mediaaltmulher = somamulher / 4;
    
    //MAIOR ALTURA TURMA
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(altura[i] > maioralt)
        {
            maioralt = altura[i];
        }
    }
    
    //MENOR ALTURA TURMA    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        if(altura[i] < menoralt)
        {
            menoralt = altura[i];
        }
    }
    
    //MEDIA ALTURA TURMA
    medaltturma = somaturma / 4;

    
    printf("\n\n ****************************************************");
    printf("\n\n               R E S U L T A D O S");
    printf("\n\n ****************************************************");
    printf("\n A média de altura das mulheres é: %0.1f", mediaaltmulher);
    printf("\n A maior altura da turma é: %0.1f", maioralt);
    printf("\n A menor altura da turma é: %0.1f", menoralt);
    printf("\n A média de altura da turma é: %0.1f", medaltturma);      
}
```

Comment: Obs: coloquei o contador até 4 [for(i=0; i<4; i++)] só pra fazer o teste mais rápido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código é bem confuso e isto ajuda dificultar o entendimento dele. O maior problema é que está contando a quantidade de mulheres, mas não acumulando as alturas, aí não tem como calcular a média corretamente. Simplificando, organizado o código ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define QUANTIDADE 4

int main() {
    printf("#######################################");
    printf("\n           ANÁLISE DE FICHAS");
    printf("\n#######################################");
    int contaMulher = 0;
    float maiorAltura = 0, menorAltura = 999, somaMulher = 0, somaAltura = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < QUANTIDADE; i++) {
        printf("\n ------------------------------------------------------------------");
        printf("\n (%d) - Qual seu gênero (1 - Masculino / 2 - Feminino): ", i + 1);
        int genero;
        scanf("%d", &genero);
        printf("\n (%d) - Insira sua altura: ", i + 1);
        float altura;
        scanf("%f", &altura);
        somaAltura += altura;
        if (genero == 2) {
            somaMulher += altura;
            contaMulher++;
        }
        if (altura > maiorAltura) maiorAltura = altura;
        if (altura < menorAltura) menorAltura = altura;
    }
    printf("\n****************************************************");
    printf("\n               R E S U L T A D O S");
    printf("\n****************************************************");
    printf("\n A média de altura das mulheres é: %0.1f", somaMulher / contaMulher);
    printf("\n A maior altura da turma é: %0.1f", maiorAltura);
    printf("\n A menor altura da turma é: %0.1f", menorAltura);
    printf("\n A média de altura da turma é: %0.1f", somaAltura / QUANTIDADE);      
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/F2ZSCu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ttgexehq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/HeightAverage.c).

Comment: Deu certo, obrigada!